# Does the first scene in Better Call Saul take place after Breaking Bad

Tags: breaking-bad, chronology, better-call-saul

In the first scene from the first episode of 'Better Call Saul', we see Saul, working at some food joint and watching his own videos at home. All this is shown in black & white. After which the story begins about Saul's early days.

My question is that whether the first scene resembles present day i.e. this where Saul is hiding after the events of Breaking Bad? Although it pretty much seems like that but is there any evidence to back that up?

Comment: Every season of Better Call Saul opens with a clip like that by the way. Not that they affect the storyline, it must be a sort-of writer's legacy to remind you that the show is a spinoff? who knows....

Comment: Black and white scenes = after Breaking Bad.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Yes.

In the second-to-last episode of Breaking Bad, Saul stated:

> "From here on out, I'm Mr. Low Profile -- just another douchebag with a job and three pairs of Dockers. If I'm lucky, a month from now, best-case scenario, I'm managing a Cinnabon in Omaha."

The first scene in Better Call Saul is that prediction come true.

Comment: really ? That's exactly what happened. Need to watch that episode again before accepting your answer :-)

Comment: @Ankit yes it is [source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uno_%28Better_Call_Saul%29)

Comment: Bugs me that Saul knew (or guessed) his fate.  I thought the **vacuum-cleaner man** (the one you call when you need to disappear) was more **discrete** than letting Saul choose.  And I thought when Saul saw his Nebraska driver's license he balked a little.  Did vacuum-cleaner man overhear the Omaha Cinnabon reference and have a cruel sense of humor?  Or just Vince Gilligan does?  Something doesn't add up...

Comment: @BobStein-VisiBone Didn't saul say the **vacuum-cleaner man** mention he let's you have a say on your destination? (when Jesse said he wanted to go to Alaska)

Comment: You're right, @Secret, but if Saul _did_ pick Nebraska, it doesn't make sense he was surprised when he got his Nebraska license. If he _didn't_ pick it, it doesn't make sense he was _casually_ surprised (having made the offhand remark to Walt). I readily admit Vince Gilligan is a master of turning a WTF situation into perfectly reasonable explanations.  E.g. burnt pink bear in a pool. E.g. pizza on a roof. However this seems like an inconsistency that got by him.

Comment: “Bugs me that Saul knew (or guessed) his fate.” Fate? There is no fate, but what we make. When Jimmy McGill said he was going to be a lawyer, he became a lawyer. And when he said he was going to be the manager of a Cinnabon, *he became the manager of a Cinnabon*.

Comment: It should be noted that other "future" scenes continue to make their way into every season premiere, so it has yet to be determined what Saul's ultimate fate is, since it is still (very slowly) unfolding with prequel (and possibley along side at some point) narrative

Answer (score 2):

Not necessarily,

Fans originally thought that the black and white future scenes at the beginning of every season take place after *Breaking Bad*, but in light of the season 4 opener, teasing a possible *Breaking Bad* character in one scene, another possibility exists, as Executive Producers Vince Gilligan, Peter Gould, and Bob Odenkirk have suggested, that they **may take place before *Breaking Bad* ends, in between episodes 5.15 & 5.16.**

**(Warning, Link Provided Has Some Possible Spoiler!!)**

> On this week's edition of the Better Call Saul Insider podcast (via
>   The Wrap), a brand new, quite intriguing curveball has been thrown
>   into the mix when it comes to those aforementioned flashfowards. While
>   speaking on the [program](https://screenrant.com/better-call-saul-flashforwards-walter-white-death/), Gilligan, Gould, and Odenkirk suggested that
>   **these sequences might be set prior to the events of Breaking Bad's
>   series finale**, and that the person "Gene" most fears the wrath of is
>   possibly ...

Comment: Now that *Better Call Saul* has ended, we can safely say that this is not the case.  I recently wrote an [answer that discusses this point](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/120265/at-what-point-in-better-call-saul-does-the-first-scene-of-breaking-bad-take-plac/120288#120288) (among others.)